# WooCommerce REST API Basic Auth not working when i'm passing basic auth

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to use woocommerce API but here I have got some issue I have created Consumer key and Consumer secret but when I'm sending a request to the server it response with **status 401 Unauthorized** I'm using basic auth and I have also tried oauth 1.0 but is not working.

[image]

Please if anyone can help me with these issue

Answer (score 0):

Basic Auth is the wrong authorization type the correct one is: OAuth1.0
Then you will have to fill in the consumer key and consumer secret in the fields required by oauth1.0 and it should work then.

Comment: Add some more details.